# Need a regular expression to split String in Python

Tags: python, regex, data-extraction

```
str = 'FW201703002082017MF0164EXESTBOPF01163500116000 0001201700258000580000116000.WALTERS BAY BOGAWANTALAWA 1M'
```

Above expression is the string need to be split and extract separately as follow:

```
Borkername = FW
Sale year = 2017
Saleno = 0300
sale_dte = 20.08.2017 # date need to be format
Factoryno = MF0164
Catalogu code= EXEST
Grade =BOPF
Gross weight =01163.50 #decimal point needed
Net Weight = 01163.50 #decimal point needed
Lot_No = 0001
invoice_year = 2017
invoice_no = 00258
price = 000580.00 #decimal point needed
Netweight = 01160.00 #decimal point needed
Buyer = 'WALTERS BAY BOGAWANTALAWA'
Buyer_code = '1M'
```

This is a single line without any denominators. So, kindly help me out to write a regular expression to separate each field to column of panda in python.

For example:

```
(\A[A-Z]{2})
```

This will give me the first 2 characters. How can I get next 4 digits as the year?

Comment: I'm having more than 10,000 similar records in the text file.

Comment: You start by typing out on the keyboard...

Comment: This is not how SO works. You should try something yourself, and if it does not work you can ask for help here.

Comment: I know exact with of each columns to be extracted, Can you help me out to extract them based on length of string.

Comment: (\A[A-Z]{2}) will give me first 2 character. How to get next 4 digits as the year.

Comment: @hiran Stack Overflow is not a free programming service, we are people who are spending our free time helping users such as yourself who have asked questions of us. What you are doing here is asking us to write something for you, this is not what this site is for. We will answer **specific** and **answerable** questions. If you want someone to write something for you, hire a programmer.

Comment: It would help if you edited the question to give some more examples for `str`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do this in two goes. First use a regular expression to split the string up into (mostly) fixed length segments. Then with the list you get back, fix the fields manually into the format you require. For example:

```
import re            
import csv

headings = [
    "Borkername", "Sale year", "Saleno", "sale_dte", "Factoryno", "Catalogu code", "Grade", "Gross weight", 
    "Net Weight", "Lot_No", "invoice_year", "invoice_no", "price", "Netweight", "Buyer", "Buyer_code"]

re_fields = re.compile(r'(.{2})(.{4})(.{3})(.{8})(.{6})(.{5})(.{4})(.{7})(.{7}) (.{4})(.{4})(.{5})(.{8})(.{7}).(.*?) (.{2})$')

with open('input.txt') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_writer.writerow(headings)

    for line in f_input:
        fields = list(re_fields.match(line).groups())

        fields[3] = "{}.{}.{}".format(fields[3][:2], fields[3][2:4], fields[3][4:])
        fields[7] = float("{}.{}".format(fields[7][:5], fields[7][5:]))
        fields[8] = float("{}.{}".format(fields[8][:5], fields[8][5:]))
        fields[12] = float("{}.{}".format(fields[12][:6], fields[12][6:]))
        fields[13] = float("{}.{}".format(fields[13][:5], fields[13][5:]))

        csv_writer.writerow(fields)
```

This would give you `output.csv` containing:

```
Borkername,Sale year,Saleno,sale_dte,Factoryno,Catalogu code,Grade,Gross weight,Net Weight,Lot_No,invoice_year,invoice_no,price,Netweight,Buyer,Buyer_code
FW,2017,030,02.08.2017,MF0164,EXEST,BOPF,1163.5,1160.0,0001,2017,00258,580.0,1160.0,WALTERS BAY BOGAWANTALAWA,1M
```

This can then be read in using Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('output.csv')
print data
```

Which gives:

```
  Borkername  Sale year  Saleno    sale_dte Factoryno Catalogu code Grade  Gross weight  Net Weight  Lot_No  \
0         FW       2017      30  02.08.2017    MF0164         EXEST  BOPF        1163.5      1160.0       1   
   invoice_year  invoice_no  price  Netweight                      Buyer Buyer_code  
0          2017         258  580.0     1160.0  WALTERS BAY BOGAWANTALAWA         1M
```

Comment: Martin., I really appreciate your help on the issue. This code is working perfectly.
As I mention earlier, there are more than 10,000 similar lines in the text file.

My intention is to import whole set of lines to panda data frame and iterate to extract attributes which has to be appear as seperate table columns. 
 import re
 import pandas as pd
 data = pd.read_csv(u'PUB05_FW_2017_AUG.txt', header=None)
(This gives me a 10000 x 1 matrix)

Comment: As a example I tried to extract one raw from the table and extract features. 
       strow = data[0:1:1].apply(str) #<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
As the re_fields = re.match() need string I tried to convert it to string with 
df.iloc[0].apply(str) gave  # <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

re_fields = re.match(r'(.{2})(.{4})(.{3})(.{8})(.{6})(.{5})(.{4})(.{7})(.{7}) (.{4})(.{4})(.{5})(.{8})(.{7}).(.*?) (.{2})$', strow)
When I try to execute above code I'm getting error as I mention below.
Error :expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: I would suggest you first convert your source text using the above logic into a proper CSV file which can then be dealt with more easily in Pandas.

Comment: Dear Martin, when I try to execute this code with correct text file name I'm getting error as below.                                                                                               Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-7-025213900e7a>", line 3, in <module>
    csv_writer.writerow(headings)

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: You are probably using Python 3.x, I have updated the script. This needed changing `open('output.csv', 'w', newline='')`

Comment: Is the script working now? If so, don't forget to click on the grey tick under the up/down buttons to select the answer as the accepted solution.

Comment: Thank you very much. Martin the Grate !!!. Appreciate  your dedicated help on this issue.